# How to store MongoDB Data

Tags: mongodb

I am building a project which can add projects in the database, In SQL I have been told that I need to store it like 1, and MongoDB store it like 2, and if no, what is the correct way to do it thanks? 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB is a document database while MySQL is a relational database. Each has its own strengths and weaknesses.

If relations and joins are important to you, maybe you should go with a relational database.

Comment: Between yes and no. Because one of the goal for me is trying to learn how to use MongoDB, so I wanted to know without relational database how will MongoDB do it, and am I doing the right way or not.

Comment: You could handle the joining of collections (mongo's table) in your application code. Doing it using queries alone is not realistic.